# sorting with dplyr's arrange within a function and piping

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem with using dplyr `arrange` within a function.

`combine_dfs` and `combine_dfs_1` do not work,
`combine_dfs_2` works, but I do not understand why this is the case.

All these function should combine 2 tibbles and then sort according to variable `time`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

df1 <- tibble(time=c(0,2),val="df1")
df2 <- tibble(time=c(1,3),val="df2")

combine_dfs <- function(...){
  data <- list(...)
  bind_rows(data) |>
    arrange("time")
}
combine_dfs(df1,df2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    time val  
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     0 df1  
#> 2     2 df1  
#> 3     1 df2  
#> 4     3 df2

combine_dfs_1 <- function(...){
  data <- list(...)
  bind_rows(data) -> xx
  xx |>
    arrange("time")
}
combine_dfs_1(df1,df2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    time val  
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     0 df1  
#> 2     2 df1  
#> 3     1 df2  
#> 4     3 df2

combine_dfs_2 <- function(...){
  data <- list(...)
  bind_rows(data) ->
    xx
    xx |>
    arrange(xx,"time")
}
combine_dfs_2(df1,df2)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>    time val  
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     0 df1  
#> 2     1 df2  
#> 3     2 df1  
#> 4     3 df2
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-16 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `combine_dfs ` works if you replace `"time"` with `time`

Comment: `arrange("time")` is sorting a length-1 static string `"time"`, it does not use the `time` variable found in the data (you can try `arrange("SOMETHING")` to see that there is no warning/error, it happily does nothing ... a symptom of R's problematic recycling). While some of the tidyverse functions will correctly use quoted names as strings (`"time"`) as well as the unquoted _symbols (`time`), not all of them work equally with both. This is an example where it _must_ have the unquoted symbol instead of the quoted string.

Comment: One may wonder why a length-1 string does nothing. R's rules allow silent recycling of any vector that is a perfect divisor of the longer length. For instance, that means that if you have a vector of length 16, then `cbind(1:16, 1:4)` recycles the second vector 4 times. All of `1:2`, `1:4`, and `1:8` work _silently_, the moment you deviate from a perfect divisor, it warns but still tries to do it. Tidyverse functions a stricter and only allow `c(1, n)`, meaning `tibble(1:16, 1:1)` and `tibble(1:16, 1:16)` work but none of the other divisors. In this case, you are seeing the length-1 version.

Comment: This will becom part of a package. My dataframes shoud contain a variable named time. When I check the package, i get a note.           make_midi_track: no visible binding for global variable ‘time’
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    time
  Consider adding
    importFrom("stats", "time")
  to your NAMESPACE file.

Answer (score 0):

Next is shown what works. You do not need quotation marks on the `ttime` variable. (Side note: I hope you allow me to rename a bit so that variable and object names do not get "basic" function names).

While/after writing this, @r2evans provides some valuable background in the comments to the question.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(ttime = c(0,2), val = "df1")
df2 <- tibble(ttime = c(1,3), val = "df2")

bind_rows(list(df1, df2)) %>% 
  arrange(ttime)

combine_dfs <- function(...){
  dat <- list(...)
  dplyr::bind_rows(dat) |>
    arrange(ttime)
  }

combine_dfs(df1,df2)

## this gives:
## A tibble: 4 × 2
#  ttime val  
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     0 df1  
#2     1 df2  
#3     2 df1  
#4     3 df2
```

Answer (score 0):

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/in-packages.html has the answer.

Within a package one has to include the directive.
`#' @importFrom rlang .data`
and then in a sequence of piped commands use
`dplyr::arrange(.data$time)`